# Sending Complete Response of a REST service as Input to another REST service in SOAP UI

Tags: rest, soapui, swagger, swagger-2.0

We have a requirement on validating the REST schema defintions. We have a REST service endpoint R1 that returns a json schema as the response when GET call is performed. We need to send that entire response json schema as input to another REST service R2 for POST call. We have 2 scenarios to deal with

a) R1 returning a normal JSON schema
b) R1 returning a Swagger definiton in JSON format.

when R1 returns a Swagger definition which has several other REST API endpoints in it, we need to pass Swagger definition as dynamic input to a REST project that constructs requests for each of those REST API endpoints in the swagger.

Is this accomplishable and can we use SOAP UI for it? Though currently SOAP UI supports importing swagger json as a static file.

Comment: There is a test case with two steps; run the step1, get the response and set it as request for the step2. Is this what you need to do?

Comment: Hi Rao. Yes. how do we set response in step1 and as the request in step2?

Comment: i figured out, but is it possible to construct multiple requests if the response is a swagger document which has several REST API endpoints

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI by default do not support swagger.

But there is an official plugin. You could give a try:

https://www.soapui.org/extension-plugins/bundled.html